# Merge MYSQL rows, totalling some columns, updating ID's in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with several tables, two of which look like this:

**players**

```
+-----+---------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+
| id  | base_id |       name        | total_searches | auctions_found | auctions_won |     created_at      |
+-----+---------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+
| 283 |  177683 | Christian Eriksen |             12 |              2 |            1 | 2019-05-29 11:25:08 |
| 160 |  177683 | Christian Eriksen |             24 |              4 |            1 | 2019-05-29 11:25:08 |
|  76 |  345345 | Yan Sommer        |             12 |              1 |            3 | 2019-05-29 11:25:08 |
| 712 |    4353 | Yannick Carrasco  |             42 |              5 |           12 | 2019-05-29 11:25:08 |
+-----+---------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

**transactions**

```
+----+-----------+---------------------+
| id | player_id |     updated_at      |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 |       283 | 2019-05-29 11:25:08 |
|  2 |       160 | 2019-05-29 11:25:08 |
|  3 |        76 | 2019-05-29 11:25:08 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
```

As you can see, there are duplicates in the players table (Christian Eriksen). I would like to merge these rows, totalling the `total_searches`, `auctions_found` and `auctions_won` columns. There are several other columns in this table (some omitted here for brevity) which are either the same (eg. `base_id`) or it's not hugely important which value is retained (eg. `created_at`).

What is important is the `id`. Either a new `id` should be created or, ideally, one of the existing `id`s retained. The transactions table would then need to be updated with the new `player_id`.

```
+-----+---------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+
| id  | base_id |       name        | total_searches | auctions_found | auctions_won |     created_at      |
+-----+---------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+
| 160 |  177683 | Christian Eriksen |             36 |              6 |            2 | 2019-05-29 11:25:08 |
|  76 |  345345 | Yan Sommer        |             12 |              1 |            3 | 2019-05-29 11:25:08 |
| 712 |    4353 | Yannick Carrasco  |             42 |              5 |           12 | 2019-05-29 11:25:08 |
+-----+---------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+

+----+-----------+---------------------+
| id | player_id |     updated_at      |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 |       160 | 2019-05-29 11:25:08 |
|  2 |       160 | 2019-05-29 11:25:08 |
|  3 |        76 | 2019-05-29 11:25:08 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
```

I don't have any knowledge of SQL so I haven't tried anything yet. Some pointers or ideally a complete solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite complicated.  I would suggest:

- Backup the tables!
- Update the id in the transactions table to be the maximum id .
- Fix the players table.
- Fix your data model.

That is:

```
update transactions t join
       players p
       on t.player_id = p.id join
       (select p2.name, max(p2.id) as max_id
        from players p2
        group by p2.name
        having count(*) > 1
       ) p2
       on p2.name = p.name  -- or should this be "base_id"
    set t.player_id = p2.max_id
    where t.player_id <> p2.max_id;
```

Then, to update the table, I recommend emptying it and recreating it:

```
create table players_temp as
    select max(id) as id,  base_id, name,
           sum(total_searches) as total_searches, 
           sum(auctions_found) as auctions_found,
           sum(auctions_won) as auctions_won,
           min(created_at) as created_at  
    from players
    group by base_id, name;  -- or whatever

truncate table players;

insert into players (id, base_id, name, total_searches, auctions_found, auctions_won, created_at)
    select id, base_id, name, total_searches, auctions_found, auctions_won, created_at
    from players_temp;
```

Then fix the data model:

```
alter table players add constraint unq_players_name
    unique (name);

alter table players add constraint unq_players_base_id
    unique (base_id);
```